# Spring test environment property indicating a test context

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

Does spring test set some environment property that I could leverage to conditionally choose between two implementations of a Spring boot auto configuration factory using the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there might be a property that the Spring test drivers set up. However, I have found a neat way of achieving my use-case via Spring Profile support.

The outline is below is for the `testng` framework. I outline the conditional wireup of the DataSource bean -- For Integration I create an embedded mysql instance. (to be replaced by a integration test managed docker mysql instance in the future).

Step 1: All Integration tests should enable the Integration Profile:

```
// Create a TestNG Base class for integration testing.
@Test(groups = "Integration")
@ActiveProfiles("Integration")
public abstract class PayliquidAbstractTestNGIntegrationTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
}

// Use the base class as follows, Leave the @SpringApplicationConfiguration on The test classes as each starter module should confine the create application context to it's configuration hierarchy.
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(TestApplication.class) 
public class SomeDaoIntegrationTest extends PayliquidAbstractTestNGIntegrationTest {
//...
}
```

Step 2: Beans can conditionally be wired up depending on the profile:

```
@Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
@Primary
@Profile("Integration")
public DataSource primaryIntegrationDatasource() {
    return JdbcClients.getIntegrationDatasource();
}
```

Step 3: Beans can be excluded based on a profile as well:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@Profile("!Integration")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    HikariDataSource hks = new HikariDataSource(datasourceConfig);

    logger.info("HikariCP MinimumIdle={}", hks.getMinimumIdle());
    logger.info("HikariCP MaxPoolSize={}", hks.getMaximumPoolSize());

    return hks;
}
```